# Why am I not getting newer files for a custom control in Sitefinity?

Tags: asp.net, caching, internet-explorer-9, sitefinity

Just a quick question. I don't use sitefinity and I don't currently have access to the backend until the site admin gets in, I'm just building the custom asp.net controls.

Anyway, in both Chrome and IE9, I've changed the settings to check for new files on every page load, emptied the cache, deleted all browsing data, restarted the browsers, used private browsing and even restarted the computer yet it's still serving an old version of the control.

I also downloaded the ascx file from the server and it is in fact the new file. Is there something that needs to be done in sitefinity to recompile the control? I didn't have this problem before when testing. Is it something the site admin might have changed without telling me?

Comment: Do you know if your sitefinity site loads its controls from a compiled library? If so, you probably need to rebuild and re-deploy a dll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are updating an old file for an existing control. If that is the case, I suspect the problem may be that Sitefinity uses a [web application project rather than a web site project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx). You need to build the whole site as a single assembly and then the new control will be taken into account.

If you are adding a new control, you should register it in the toolbox again and then put it on a page in Sitefinity. If I have misunderstood the question, I'd need the exact steps you are following to help better.